# Active Record - automatically generating markdown in the model

Tags: ruby, activerecord, markdown, mixins

I'm writing a Ruby module to provide automatic markdown generation on blog posts etc.

The code so far looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  contains_markdown
end

module MarkdownMixin
  def contains_markdown
    # HELP! :)
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :extend, MarkdownMixin
```

That code seems to be working (i.e. my unit tests don't throw any 'not defined' errors etc.). The `Post` table contains an `input` and `formatted` column.

Where I've written `# HELP` I want to inject code to the `Post` model so that whenever a change is made to `input`, `formatted` is recalculated (using a Markdown engine). Something like (pseudo-code):

```
def on_input_changed
  @formatted = Redcarpet.new(@input).to_html
end
```

Now I'm still really getting my head around Ruby mixins so my brain's slightly spinning trying to work out what incantation to call in my module.

So far I've found [this article](http://onehub.com/blog/posts/decorating-activerecord-accessor-methods/) quite useful, but can't work out how to apply it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use a `before_save` where you make the transformation.

```
def contains_markdown
  before_save do |record|
    record.formatted = Redcarpet.new(record.input).to_html
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd read about the `before_save` hook. Do you know what code I'd use to inject it into the `Post` class?

Comment: You can use it in your contains_markdown method. There's a great example here : https://github.com/ryanb/uniquify/blob/master/lib/uniquify.rb